# React Js - Error al consumir datos de API utilizando Fetch en React Js

Tags: reactjs, api, fetch

Estoy realizando una app en, la cual, requiero los datos de una API, para ello utilizo Fetch, al momento de efectuarlo e intentar imprimir datos en consola, se indica indefinido, es decir, no se muestran los datos. y posteriormente se indica un error.

El código de la función es el siguiente:

```
const App = () => {
    const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState();

    const get_weather_data = () => {
        fetch('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/368148/', {
          method: 'GET',
          mode: 'no-cors'  
        }) 
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => setWeatherData(data))
       .catch(err => console.log(err))
       console.log(weatherData)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => get_weather_data()}>Obtain data</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at App.jsx:51
```

Comment: cuando haces un get no es necesario poner un segundo parámetro al fetch, tambien veo que todo parece bien, supongo que el error se recibe en el catch, qué tipo de error te aparece????

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, ya edité la pregunta estableciendo el error. En cuanto al segundo parámetro, lo añado debido a que de otro medo obtengo el siguiente error:          


localhost/:1 Access to fetch at 'https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/368148/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: nunca me ha ocurrido esto pero aqui hay una pregunta parecida, parece que tiene que ver con la cabecera no-cors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317967/handle-response-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input-when-using-mode-no-cors

Comment: Te comparto este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KHiSt0oLJ0 donde explican muy bien qué es CORS y cómo solucionarlo