# Node js - Consumir API

Tags: nodejs, api

Estoy creando una app, en la cual se debe consumir una API, lo he intentado desde el frontend con "Axios" y "fetch API", sin embargo no ha funcionado debido a la política de "cors", y para ello me han recomendado un video en donde se da ha conocer la siguiente solución:

```
const express = require('express');
const app =  express();
const morgan = require('morgan');

const cors = require('cors');

// settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000)
app.use(cors({origin: 'https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/368148/'})) //Éste es el enlace de la API

// midelwares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());

// routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send({'Title': 'Hello World'})
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`Server on port ${app.get('port')}`)
});
```

¿Cómo podría consumir los datos de la API?

Comment: El origin que declaraste desde CORS es cuando una api va a consumir los recursos de tu API... y por lo que entiendo, tú situación es lo inverso. Es decir, tú API va a consumir los recursos de www.metaweather.com. Puedo ver ¿cómo estás ejecutando el fetch hacia la API?

Comment: Hola, por supuesto, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/471541/react-js-error-al-consumir-datos-de-api-utilizando-fetch-en-react-js?noredirect=1#comment843308_471541, ese es el enlace donde encontrarás cómo estoy realizando el fetch, y a su vez estará ahí el vídeo que me recomendaron para una posible solución.

Answer (score 1):

La opcion mas sencilla es usar un middleware, para express esta [este paquete de npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors), es muy sencillo de implementar:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors())
```

Answer (score 1):

lo que pasa es que algunos navegadores de forma predeterminada tienen restringido las solicitudes de origen cruzado por parte del frontend, a excepción cuando el sitio envía un Access-Control-Allow-Origin en las respuestas.

En tu caso no debe haber forma de que puedas acceder solamente habilitando las cors ya que esto bloquea restringe el cuerpo de respuesta y cabecera.

Intenta establecer el proxy en tu json de esta manera:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "proxy": "https://www.metaweather.com",
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    ...
}
```

luego ya puedes utilizar axios o fetch:

```
fetch(`/api/location/368148/`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log('data', data))
.catch(error => console.log('error:', error));
```

Te dejo un link donde muestra las diversas formas de solucionarlo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxyp_LkKDdk&ab_channel=HongLy

Saludos c: